# Optional parameters in Visual Studio 2008 Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, asp.net-3.5, optional-parameters

I am developing a Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2008.

I am trying to implement optional parameters so that a user does not have to specify a value or range for a particular field. Essentially, this means there is no filtering done on that field if the user wishes.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: do you want to know how to add optional parameters to the report or how to (not) filter data in the database based on their value?

Answer (score 0):

You might find this approach helpful: [Crystal Reports: Optional-Multi-Select Parameters](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/24/crystal-reports-optional-multi-select-parameters/).